# How to add a checkboxcell in cellTable, which will enable/disable based on the boolean property in my object, while it is initialising

Tags: gwt

I want to create a `CellTable` that has two columns. My first column is a checkbox cell and my second column is a text cell, I want my first column to be populated based on the boolean property in my class.

Example: `Employee` is the class instance and `isPresented` is the boolean value. I want to list the details of the employee which will by default check the presented employees and uncheck the absented employees.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AbstractCell<Boolean> checkBoxCell = new AbstractCell<Boolean>()
{

@Override
public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, Boolean value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) 
{
   sb.appendHtmlConstant("<input type='check' " + (value ? "checked='1'" : "")+ "'/>");
}};

CellTable<Employee> cellTable = new CellTable<Employee>();

cellTable.addColumn(new Column<Employee, Boolean>(checkBoxCell) 
{
   @Override
   public Boolean getValue(Employee object) 
   {
      return object.isPresented;
   }
});

cellTable.addColumn(... // TextColumn
```